# Tomcat 6 log4j - linux - safely remove catalina.out

Tags: linux, tomcat, log4j

Adding log4j [1] in tomcat 6.0.x forces tomcat to produce logs in "catalina" file. However, the default catalina.out is still produced and populated with logs. So, questions:

Is it safe to delete catalina.out file (while server running)? 
If yes, could this deletion be added to tomcat startup script? If yes, could anyone please point out the file and the required script?
Is it possible for tomcat to stop createing the catalina.out, since it is not nessesary anymore?

1. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html

Thanks in advance people!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tomcat redirects its stdout and stderr to catalina.out. So direct out/err writes and log4j ConsoleAppender messages will go to catalina.out. See [catalina.sh file](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/tc6.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_6_0_35/bin/catalina.sh?view=markup) for details. To disable it completely you can redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null setting CATALINA_OUT environment variable:

```
export CATALINA_OUT=/dev/null
```

But I recommend to disable ConsoleAppender instead to reduce catalina.out size and monitor it periodically looking for error messages, that may go to stdout bypassing log4j.

Comment: You recommend disabling ConsoleAppender but don't mention how to do that.

Comment: .handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

Answer (score 0):

If the `catalina.out` is deleted after `tomcat` is stopped, it will create a new `catalina.out` once `tomcat` starts again and it is totally safe.

But if you remove the `catalina.out` while `tomcat` is running, it will keep on logging to `catalina.out` which is removed already (reference of the file is hold by the `tomcat`) hence the space will not be released. So you will need to restart the `tomcat` sever to release the space. It is not recommended.

You can try following to disable writing to `catalina.out` :

1. Locate and Edit File: {CATALINA_BASE}/bin/catalina.sh

Locate "**CATALINA_OUT**" and replace the path with "**/dev/null**":

```
 CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out // Original Location
 CATALINA_OUT=/dev/null // replace path to /dev/null
```

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason you'd want to delete the catalina.out file? It seems like it might lead to potentially missing important event messages. Perhaps consider just setting

`org.apache.catalina.level=INFO`

Otherwise I can't think of a reason that it would negatively impact the functionality of the container if you deleted it. On a *nix install its still writing to the file descriptor of a file that is  diconnected from an inode(so otherwise unreachable) and on windows it won't let you delete it because the container will have a file lock.

[logging docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/logging.html) - a quick rtfm and it looks like you should just be able to remove the handlers from logging.properties to discontinue producing this file

Comment: The reason for deleting catalina.out is because, due to the use of log4j, tomcat logs are now produced in another file "catalina". So we have the same logs twice. Moreover, catalina.out gets really big.

Comment: You should refer to the documentation, but in my experience there are certain messages that seem to only find their way into catalina. Specifically those related to classpath issues and fatal container errors. I would suggest reducing the verbosity of your catalina logging settings.

Comment: Please note that I dont want to reduce verbosity, moreover as I noted before those logs that you are refering to, are now produced in one more file as well, thus catalina.out is useless (since Im not interested in the standard output of the server)

Comment: read my update. I think you can just remove the file handlers from logging.properties and it will stop appending those logging events to the files.

Comment: What you suggest is not possible. From tomcat documentation, regarding tomcat integration with log4j: "Delete $CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties to prevent java.util.logging generating zero length log files".

Comment: Sweet downvote then basically accepting the same answer from someone two days later. Good luck trouble shooting a production issue with your standard out/err being piped to /dev/null