# Tomcat logging in webapp and container?

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j

I have log4j configured in my webapp (which works well) and was looking to move from Juli to log4j at the container (tomcat) level. I have added the relevant jars to tomcat bin / lib directory and a log4j.properties to the lib directory. It seems this configuration is ignored by tomcat.

My questions is, as I have configured log4j in my webapp and all stdout/errout messages are directed to catalina.out (via the tomcat java process)... do I even need a log configuration at the container level?

Thanks in advance for any responses :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems this configuration is ignored by tomcat.

Try to recheck your tomcat setup, [these config steps](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j) are not simple, but definitely works after done exactly as they stated.

After that you will have your container level log config in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib/log4j.properties`.
So to control tomcat's itself output you can add lines like these:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.tomcat=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.coyote=INFO
```

Concerning catalina.out file - see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9692553/314015).